# Programmatically get servers certificates

Tags: java, ssl, jboss, certificate

I've configured my JBoss AS7 SSL like this:

```
<connector
    name="https"
    protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    scheme="https"
    socket-binding="https"
    enable-lookups="false"
    secure="true">
        <ssl
            name="foo-ssl"
            key-alias="server"
            password="123456"
            certificate-key-file="../standalone/configuration/server.keystore"
            protocol="TLS"
            verify-client="false"
            ca-certificate-file="../standalone/configuration/server.keystore"
        />
</connector>
```

And I'm wondering if there's any change that I can programmatically access the certificates defined in this keystore, but without specific its path in the Java code

I've tried this

```
  TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
  tmf.init((KeyStore) null);

  // Get hold of the default trust manager
  X509TrustManager x509Tm = null;
  for (TrustManager tm : tmf.getTrustManagers())
  {
    if (tm instanceof X509TrustManager)
    {
      x509Tm = (X509TrustManager) tm;
      break;
    }
  }

  for (X509Certificate currentCertificate : x509Tm.getAcceptedIssuers())
  {
    System.out.println(currentCertificate.getIssuerX500Principal().toString());
  }
```

but id didn't show up the certificates present on the keystore.